# Avconv broadcasting video stream

Tags: linux, bash, streaming, video-streaming, avconv

I'm doing some test for broadcasting a video stream.

I try with:

```
 avconv -i video.mov -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://[destinationIP]:1234
```

And from "destinationIP" I can play the stream.

But, how can I specify **a range of IP** and not a single IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution searching on web, especially reading this [page](http://gelliphanindraviswanadhaprasad.org/videolan-streaming-howto/).

For transmit video:

```
avconv -i video.mov -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://224.0.0.100:1234
```

From any client in the lan:

```
mplayer udp://224.0.0.100:1234
```

The trick is to trasmit to the multicast group with the ip range:

```
. from 224.0.0.0   
. to   239.255.255.255
```

'1234' is the port used to stream.

Comment: i don't see you transmitting to unicast, where is it?